# Eigenvalues of $A+P^{-1} \alpha A P$ where A is a diagonal matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Let A be a diagonal matrix of size $N$. I am trying to find the eigenvalues of $A+P^{-1} \alpha A P$ where $\alpha$ is a real number. Here is my attempt:

\begin{equation}
(A+P^{-1} \alpha A P)v=\lambda v,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(P^{-1} \alpha A P)v=(\lambda I - A) v,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(\alpha A P)v=P(\lambda I - A) v,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Lv=R v,
\end{equation}

where $L=\alpha A P$ and $R=P(\lambda I - A)$. Assuming that $v\neq 0$, we can conclude that $L=R$ (?). Therefore, by equating corresponding elements of L and R:

\begin{equation}
l_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\alpha a_{ik}p_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}p_{ik}(\lambda 1_{kj} - a_{kj})=r_{ij}
\end{equation}

Since A is a digonal matrix, $a_{ij} = 0$ for $i \neq j$. Hence,

\begin{equation}
\lambda = a_{ii}+\alpha a_{jj}
\end{equation}

Question 1: Is my calculation correct?

Question 2: How do I proceed from here to find the $N$ eigenvalues? Since $i$ and $j$ can be anything from $1$ to $N$, from this calculation, it looks like that there are $N^{2}$ eigenvalues! This is a sign that I did something wrong, but I cannot find where it went wrong.

Comment: "Assuming that $v \neq 0$, we can conclude that $L=R$ (?)" I'm afraid not. Otherwise any matrix with a non-trivial nullspace would be the $0$ matrix.

Comment: Very good point. Thanks.
Do you have any suggestion in finding the eigenvalues of this matrix?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. I'm not convinced that the eigenvalues of this matrix are even a function of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\alpha$, but I could be wrong. Is this some kind of exercise? Basically, is there a reason you think this question has an answer?

Comment: No, it is not an exercise and I am not sure whether this question has an answer either. It appeared in my research. If I manage to find the eigenvalues of this matrix analytically it just simplifies the other calculations that I have.

Comment: I did a little playing around in Sagemath, and it looks like there isn't going to be a satisfactory answer to this. Keeping $A$ and $\alpha$ constant, while varying $P$, produces different eigenvalues. So, any formula for the eigenvalues will have to take into account the nitty-gritty particulars of $P$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time.